# Why Tencent.onActivityResult is not defined when using QQ Android SDK

Tags: java, android, sdk

I was following the QQ Android SDK instruction (http://wiki.connect.qq.com/%E5%88%9B%E5%BB%BA%E5%AE%9E%E4%BE%8B%E5%B9%B6%E5%AE%9E%E7%8E%B0%E5%9B%9E%E8%B0%83_android_sdk)

In the last step, I tried to add `tencent.onActivityResult` into the `onActivityResult` method, but it always say that the onActivityResult is not defined in Tencent object.

Has anyone seen the same error? And how could I solve this problem?

I appreciate any help that you can provide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SDK has been updated on this part since version 2.1. You are no longer required to invoke the onActivityResult with the Tencent object. But instead, they are now having an activity responsible for handling passing result across the authentication activites. The only thing you need to do is to include the AssistActivity and AuthActivity in your AndroidManifest.xml.

You can have a look on the AndroidManifest.xml included in the sample directory.

This is the link talking about the changes but it is written in simplifed chinese. See if you are able to read it.

http://wiki.open.qq.com/wiki/mobile/Android_SDK%E4%BD%BF%E7%94%A8%E8%AF%B4%E6%98%8E